# inline-block element is outside parent, left floated element is inside

Tags: html, css

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ohewuanx/

I'm working on part of a CSS lib with a react implementation, implementing a progress bar. It worked great in tests on the css side, but as soon as I implemented it in react, the actual filled bar was outside of its container. It sits a few pixels down. I realized the css tests didn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the test files. Adding it broke the style, or revealed my already broken style.

I managed to fix it by swapping out

```html
.progress-bar > * {
    background: #008be1;
    height: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

for

```html
.progress-bar > * {
    background: #008be1;
    height: 4px;
    float: left;
}
```

but I have no idea why that fixed it, or why it didn't work in the first place. Heights are given, it's an inline-block element inside a block parent. There are no margins or paddings present. Why is the child div offset instead of being contained in the parent?

Comment: add `vertical-align: top;` (adding more duplicate but basically it's alignment issue)

Comment: `font-size:0` on the parent will also fix the issue

Comment: I played around with your jsfiddle, and I believe `line-height` was causing the issue when your `.progress-bar *` was `display: inline-block;`. Even though you don't have any text here, there's still a default `line-height` applied to elements. While `.progress-bar *` is `display: inline-block;`, if you add `line-height: 0;` to `.progress-bar`, that extra whitespace is gone, and your progress bar works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both display:inline-block and float from that class. Why even add those

`.progress-bar > * {
    background: #008be1;
    height: 4px;
}`